# New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, azure-rm-template

Quite strange, It was all working well, but suddenly I started getting this message for ARM Deployment. I have even completed 10 webapp deployment with the script before as part of testing:**New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment**

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                                       -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                                       -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParameterFileAzureLocalLink `
                                                       -Force -Verbose
```

==============================Error Message is as below ================

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 6:33:49 PM - "Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for 
details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details."
At D:\Azure\trial\runscript_localfiles_working_june6.ps1:116 char:25
+                         New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'error'
At D:\Azure\trial\runscript_localfiles_working_june6.ps1:116 char:25
+                         New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], RuntimeBinderException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand
```

Any suggestions as this is making me freak out! :(

Thanks in advance for the consideration

Comment: I tried the same using azure portal and got the following : Failed to submit deployment.

Comment: Error submitting the deployment request. Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: The value of deployment parameter 'administratorLogin' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details. (Code: InvalidDeploymentParameterValue) >> Any suggestion please

Comment: Debugging gives me DB Server conflict. It is the only conflict but I was thinking to use one DB server with each application databases created within.. Request some help.

Comment: PF the error message logged as : "error": { "code": "DeploymentFailed", "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details": [{"code": "Conflict", "message": "{\r\n  \"code\": \"60080\",\r\n  \"message\": \"Server name automationpilotsrvrtrialrun111' has already been used.\",\r\n  \"target\": null,\r\n  \"details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"code\": \"60080\",\r\n      \"message\": \"Server name 'automationpilotsrvrtrialrun111' has already been used.\",\r\n   .......}]}}}

Comment: Interestingly, if I provide a new DB server name, this works charm but do not let create of app database using existing db even if in same resource group! Neither database per server limit applies as it got hardly 2 databases..

Comment: Without seeing your template, it is difficult to pinpoint the problem. But from your error messages, it looks like a parameter is missing, and you are using a server name that is already in use. If you want to have a unique name for your server, use the uniqueString function in your template.

Comment: @EdRixon Yes, I was using a name already in use. I had corrected it.